# Android Twitter Kit crash when authenticate again after cancel

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I am using TwitterKit v2.3.0

```
com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0@aar
```

Here is how I call Twitter Authentication using `TwitterAuthClient`:

```
        if (mTwitterAuthClient == null) {
            TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.twitter_api_key),
                    getString(R.string.twitter_api_secret));
            Fabric.with(getActivity(), new Twitter(authConfig));
        }
        mTwitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
        mTwitterAuthClient.authorize(getActivity(), new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                handleTwitterSession(result.data);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            }
       });
```

If I press login button, then press back or cancel button to close authentication screen, then press login button again, it throws an exception without showing authentication screen again:

```
01-13 21:34:40.689 10842-10842/com.ihnel.mclearning W/Twitter: Authorize already in progress
01-13 21:34:40.689 10842-10842/com.ihnel.mclearning E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
                                                               com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
                                                                   at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.handleAuthorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:110)
                                                                   at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.authorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:101)
                                                                   at com.binh.auth.fragment.LoginFragment.loginWithTwitter(LoginFragment.java:157)
                                                                   at com.binh.auth.databinding.AuthFragmentLoginBinding$OnClickListenerImpl2.onClick(AuthFragmentLoginBinding.java:273)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I checked the Twitter Core source code, It keeps a static instance of `AuthState`, where never be renew although I recreate new instance of TwitterAuthClient. 
Does someone know how to bypass this exception?

Answer (score 3):

Found a similar thread in Twitter Community : https://twittercommunity.com/t/getting-authorization-error-when-cancelling-from-twitter-authorization-using-fabric-sdk/31341/10

The issue gone when I implement `onActivityResult` method in my activity as below:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        final TwitterAuthClient twitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
        if(twitterAuthClient.getRequestCode()==requestCode) {
            twitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

But, this just a workaround like what they said. I hope we will got a final better solution.